# Как выполнить проверку на null в rxjava2

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Вот есть такой метод

```
public void updateDependedQuestionsIfNeeded(ServicePartFormQuestion mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion)
{
    try
    {
        if (mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion != null && mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion.getDependedQuestions() != null)
        {
            Observable.fromIterable(mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion.getDependedQuestions())//
                      .filter(//
                              iServicePartFormQuestion -> iServicePartFormQuestion != null //
                                      && iServicePartFormQuestion.getAnswerFieldTypeWithCorrection() == ServicePartFormQuestion.eAnswerFieldType.ClosedList//
                      )//
                      .map(iServicePartFormQuestion -> getVisibleQuestions().indexOf(iServicePartFormQuestion))//
                      .filter(iInteger -> iInteger > -1)//
                      .forEach(this::notifyItemDataChanged);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignored)
    {
    }
}
```

Как можно избавиться от это строчки проверки

```
if (mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion != null && mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion.getDependedQuestions() != null)
```

Я так понимаю, что сначала нужно как то проверить, что сам обьект не null , если нет, то сделать `flatMap()` и забрать из него `getDependedQuestion()` проверить если он тоже не null и если нет, то тогда уже работать с ним как описано в моем примере...

Только не пойму как сделать проверку на null

**EDIT**

Теперь ясно, что Rx не работает с null и нужно поставить `onError()` обработчик, но все равно не понятно куда его прицепить в моем случае

```
public void updateDependedQuestionsIfNeeded(ServicePartFormQuestion mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion)
{
    Observable.just(mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion)//
              .flatMap(//
                      iServicePartFormQuestion -> Observable.fromIterable(iServicePartFormQuestion.getDependedQuestions())//
              )//
              .cast(ServicePartFormQuestion.class)//
              .filter(//
                      iServicePartFormQuestion -> iServicePartFormQuestion != null //
                              && iServicePartFormQuestion.getAnswerFieldTypeWithCorrection() == ServicePartFormQuestion.eAnswerFieldType.ClosedList//
              )//
              .map(iServicePartFormQuestion -> getVisibleQuestions().indexOf(iServicePartFormQuestion))//
              .filter(iInteger -> iInteger > -1)//
              .forEach(this::notifyItemDataChanged);
}
```

Comment: rxjava2 не работает с null объектами, так что можно ничего не проверять, вам упадёт ошибка в onError :)

Comment: @SviatVolkov Добавил в вопрос то, что получилось. Все равно не пойму куда прицепить обработчик

Comment: в методе subscribe() есть второй параметр. это Consumer в который будут падать ошибки

Comment: @SviatVolkov аа, все понял... Меня просто запутал метод `forEach()` после которого нет `subscribe()` метода. Теперь ясно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось вот так

```
public void updateDependedQuestionsIfNeeded(ServicePartFormQuestion mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion)
{
    Observable.just(mCurrentServicePartFormQuestion)//
              .flatMap(//
                      iServicePartFormQuestion -> Observable.fromIterable(iServicePartFormQuestion.getDependedQuestions())//
              )//
              .cast(ServicePartFormQuestion.class)//
              .filter(//
                      iServicePartFormQuestion -> iServicePartFormQuestion != null //
                              && iServicePartFormQuestion.getAnswerFieldTypeWithCorrection() == ServicePartFormQuestion.eAnswerFieldType.ClosedList//
              )//
              .map(iServicePartFormQuestion -> getVisibleQuestions().indexOf(iServicePartFormQuestion))//
              .filter(iInteger -> iInteger > -1)//
              .subscribe(//
                      this::notifyItemDataChanged, //
                      iThrowable -> AppUtils.printLog(Log.ERROR, TAG, iThrowable.getMessage())//
              );
}
```